Trying to optimize my ARPLS implementation
I'm trying to optimize my spectral baseline fitting algorithm (based on this one), since, from my understanding, NumPy's apply_along_axis performance is not significantly higher than simply looping through an array's indices.
It currently takes ~0.15 seconds to process a spectrum of ~4000 wavelengths, but applied to millions of spectra, it would take a while, to say the least. Am I missing an obvious vectorized solution, or is the algorithm simply that heavy? Example spectra file provided here, and its respective baseline here.
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy.sparse import csc_array, csr_array, dia_array, diags_array, eye_array
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve


# Sparse array implementation
def arpls(
    spectrum: NDArray[np.floating],
    smoothing_factor: float = 1E6,
    convergence_tolerance: float = 0.05,
    differentiation_order: int = 2,
    max_iterations: int = 100,
    edge_padding: int = 100,
) -> NDArray[np.floating]:
    """
    Fits a baseline signal to the given spectrum using Asymmetrically Reweighted Penalized Least Squares smoothing.

    ### Parameters
    - spectrum: `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The 1D spectrum input array.
    - smoothing_factor: `float`, optional -- Smoothing strength parameter.\
        The larger the parameter, the smoother the resulting baseline.\
        High values suppress small fluctuations, which may lead to a smoother but less sensitive baseline.
    - convergence_tolerance: `float`, optional -- Convergence criterion based on the change in weights between iterations.\
        Must be a value between 0 and 1. Smaller values allow less negative deviations, promoting a more accurate baseline fitting.
    - differentiation_order: `int`, optional -- The order of the difference operator used in penalization.\
        An order of 1 enforces a linear baseline (smoothing the first derivative), while an order of 2 enforces a quadratic baseline (smoothing the second derivative).\
        Higher orders allow for more complex baseline shapes.
    - max_iterations: `int`, optional -- Maximum number of iterations to perform.\
        The algorithm iteratively refines the baseline until the convergence criterion is met or the maximum number of iterations is reached.
    - edge_padding: `int`, optional -- Number of points to pad on both ends of the spectrum to improve baseline fitting at the edges.\
        Padding is done using edge values to minimize boundary effects.

    ### Returns
    - `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The fitted baseline signal array of the same length as the input spectrum (after removing padding).

    ### Raises
    - `ValueError` -- If the ratio is not between 0 and 1.

    ### Reference
    - https://irfpy.irf.se/projects/ica/api/api_irfpy.ica.baseline.html#irfpy.ica.baseline.arpls

    ### Notes
    The ARPLS algorithm is particularly useful for baseline correction in spectra where the baseline is not well-defined and varies in a complex way.
    The algorithm iteratively adjusts the baseline by penalizing large deviations while allowing for asymmetric weighting, making it robust for various types of spectral data.
    """

    # Step 1: Pad the spectrum to reduce boundary effects during baseline fitting.
    padded_spectrum = np.pad(spectrum, pad_width=edge_padding, mode="edge")
    # Step 2: Initialize the weights array.
    current_weights = np.ones_like(padded_spectrum)

    # Step 3: Initialize a difference array for enforcing smoothness
    differences: csr_array = eye_array(padded_spectrum.shape[0], dtype=np.float64, format="csr")
    for _ in range(differentiation_order):
        # Update the difference array to account for higher-order differentials if required
        differences = differences[1:] - differences[:-1]

    # Step 4: Compute the smoothness penalties using the difference matrix and smoothing factor
    smoothness_penalies: csc_array = smoothing_factor * (differences.T @ differences)

    # Step 5: Iteratively refine the estimated baseline
    baseline = np.zeros_like(padded_spectrum)
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # Step 5a: Generate a diagonal weights array from the current weights
        diagonal_weights: dia_array = diags_array(current_weights, dtype=np.float64, format="dia")
        # Step 5b: Solve for the baseline using the current weights and smoothness penalties
        baseline[:] = spsolve(diagonal_weights + smoothness_penalies, current_weights * padded_spectrum, permc_spec="NATURAL")

        # Step 5c: Calculate residuals (difference between the actual spectrum and the baseline)
        residuals = padded_spectrum - baseline
        # Step 5d: Calculate statistics of the negative residuals. Negative residuals indicate regions where the baseline may be overestimated
        negative_residuals = residuals[residuals < 0]
        nr_mean: np.floating = negative_residuals.mean(dtype=np.float64)
        nr_deviation: np.floating = negative_residuals.std(dtype=np.float64)

        # Step 5e: Update the weights to penalize large deviations while allowing for asymmetry. This step adjusts the baseline fitting to be more sensitive to regions below the baseline
        # Potential overflow in the original algorithm: "np.exp(2.0 * (residuals - ((2 * nr_deviation) - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation)"
        exponents = 2 * (residuals - (2 * nr_deviation - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation
        exponents.clip(-500, 500, out=exponents)
        updated_weights = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(exponents, dtype=np.float64))

        # Step 5f: Check for convergence by measuring how much the weights have changed
        if (norm(current_weights - updated_weights) / norm(current_weights)) < convergence_tolerance:
            break # Stop iterating if the change in weights is below the specified tolerance
        current_weights[:] = updated_weights

    # Step 6: Remove the padding and return the baseline corresponding to the original spectrum
    return baseline[edge_padding:-edge_padding]

# (M, N) spectra, where M is the number of signals acquired and N, the amount of wavelengths each signal contains
spectra = np.loadtxt("spectra.csv", dtype=np.float32, delimiter=",")

baseline = np.apply_along_axis(arpls, axis=1, arr=spectra)
np.savetxt("baseline.csv", baseline, delimiter=",")


If you use a tool like line_profiler, where does it say that it is spending most of its time?

A (fully) minimal reproducible example or detailed profiling informations are missing in this question. Besides, you should show what did you tried.

"applied to millions of spectra" Multithreading is the key to speed up the independent computations.

"Am I missing an obvious vectorized solution" Regarding the code, I do not think there is any simple one. This is not rare for complex solution, especially for algorithm operating on sparse structures.

"is the algorithm simply that heavy?" Generally no, at least, as long as you do not have constraints like "using only Numpy or Scipy" which are certainly far from being optimal here. For example, there are a lot of expensive (useless) temporary arrays created in this code and there is a loop in the function (which are slow in CPython not to mention each Numpy function has a significant overhead on small arrays)

I uploaded a sample spectra file, along with their resulting baselines. Note that I limited the spectra to ~2000 wavelengths, since there is a spectral cutoff around that point.

I don't think there's anything that will make this wildly faster - it spends the majority of its time in spsolve(), and that's already written in C. To make this much faster, you would somehow need to avoid solving this matrix, and I don't understand the math here well enough to think of an alternative which doesn't involve solving a matrix.
However, I did find two ideas that can make this around 36% faster.

Faster diagonal manipulation
Caching the creation of the penalty matrix

The first thing I did was profile the program. I noticed that the program spent a lot of time on the spsolve line, so I broke that line up into multiple lines.
A = diagonal_weights + smoothness_penalies
b = current_weights * padded_spectrum
baseline[:] = spsolve(A, b, permc_spec="NATURAL")

Then I profiled this.
    69      1203  569457223.0 473364.3     22.6          A = diagonal_weights + smoothness_penalies
    70      1203    4759976.0   3956.8      0.2          b = current_weights * padded_spectrum
    71      1203 1352957577.0    1e+06     53.7          baseline[:] = spsolve(A, b, permc_spec="NATURAL")

Spending 53.7% of its time in spsolve is hard to reduce, for the reasons I just mentioned. However, 22.6% of its time is also spent adding two matrices together, which seems crazy to me. I think this is some combination of overhead from converting DIA to CSC, and CSC + CSC addition being slow.
Faster diagonal manipulation
As an alternative, I tried identifying the indices of diagonal elements, the initial value of those elements, and then manipulating the diagonal elements directly using NumPy.
# Sparse array implementation
def arpls(
    spectrum: NDArray[np.floating],
    smoothing_factor: float = 1E6,
    convergence_tolerance: float = 0.05,
    differentiation_order: int = 2,
    max_iterations: int = 100,
    edge_padding: int = 100,
) -> NDArray[np.floating]:
    """
    Fits a baseline signal to the given spectrum using Asymmetrically Reweighted Penalized Least Squares smoothing.

    ### Parameters
    - spectrum: `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The 1D spectrum input array.
    - smoothing_factor: `float`, optional -- Smoothing strength parameter.\
        The larger the parameter, the smoother the resulting baseline.\
        High values suppress small fluctuations, which may lead to a smoother but less sensitive baseline.
    - convergence_tolerance: `float`, optional -- Convergence criterion based on the change in weights between iterations.\
        Must be a value between 0 and 1. Smaller values allow less negative deviations, promoting a more accurate baseline fitting.
    - differentiation_order: `int`, optional -- The order of the difference operator used in penalization.\
        An order of 1 enforces a linear baseline (smoothing the first derivative), while an order of 2 enforces a quadratic baseline (smoothing the second derivative).\
        Higher orders allow for more complex baseline shapes.
    - max_iterations: `int`, optional -- Maximum number of iterations to perform.\
        The algorithm iteratively refines the baseline until the convergence criterion is met or the maximum number of iterations is reached.
    - edge_padding: `int`, optional -- Number of points to pad on both ends of the spectrum to improve baseline fitting at the edges.\
        Padding is done using edge values to minimize boundary effects.

    ### Returns
    - `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The fitted baseline signal array of the same length as the input spectrum (after removing padding).

    ### Raises
    - `ValueError` -- If the ratio is not between 0 and 1.

    ### Reference
    - https://irfpy.irf.se/projects/ica/api/api_irfpy.ica.baseline.html#irfpy.ica.baseline.arpls

    ### Notes
    The ARPLS algorithm is particularly useful for baseline correction in spectra where the baseline is not well-defined and varies in a complex way.
    The algorithm iteratively adjusts the baseline by penalizing large deviations while allowing for asymmetric weighting, making it robust for various types of spectral data.
    """

    # Step 1: Pad the spectrum to reduce boundary effects during baseline fitting.
    padded_spectrum = np.pad(spectrum, pad_width=edge_padding, mode="edge")
    # Step 2: Initialize the weights array.
    current_weights = np.ones_like(padded_spectrum)

    # Step 3: Initialize a difference array for enforcing smoothness
    differences: csr_array = eye_array(padded_spectrum.shape[0], dtype=np.float64, format="csr")
    for _ in range(differentiation_order):
        # Update the difference array to account for higher-order differentials if required
        differences = differences[1:] - differences[:-1]

    # Step 4: Compute the smoothness penalties using the difference matrix and smoothing factor
    smoothness_penalies: csc_array = smoothing_factor * (differences.T @ differences)
    smoothness_penalies = smoothness_penalies.tocoo()
    smoothness_penalies.sum_duplicates()
    # smoothness_penalies must have canonical format, or changing to csr could change
    # data order
    assert smoothness_penalies.has_canonical_format
    initial_diag_index = np.where(smoothness_penalies.row == smoothness_penalies.col)[0]
    
    initial_diag = smoothness_penalies.data[initial_diag_index]
    smoothness_penalies = smoothness_penalies.tocsr()
    assert (smoothness_penalies.data[initial_diag_index] == smoothness_penalies.diagonal()).all()
    A = smoothness_penalies.copy()

    # Step 5: Iteratively refine the estimated baseline
    baseline = np.zeros_like(padded_spectrum)
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # Step 5a: Generate a diagonal weights array from the current weights
        A.data[initial_diag_index] = initial_diag + current_weights
        # Step 5b: Solve for the baseline using the current weights and smoothness penalties
        b = current_weights * padded_spectrum
        baseline[:] = spsolve(A, b, permc_spec="NATURAL")

        # Step 5c: Calculate residuals (difference between the actual spectrum and the baseline)
        residuals = padded_spectrum - baseline
        # Step 5d: Calculate statistics of the negative residuals. Negative residuals indicate regions where the baseline may be overestimated
        negative_residuals = residuals[residuals < 0]
        nr_mean: np.floating = negative_residuals.mean(dtype=np.float64)
        nr_deviation: np.floating = negative_residuals.std(dtype=np.float64)

        # Step 5e: Update the weights to penalize large deviations while allowing for asymmetry. This step adjusts the baseline fitting to be more sensitive to regions below the baseline
        # Potential overflow in the original algorithm: "np.exp(2.0 * (residuals - ((2 * nr_deviation) - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation)"
        exponents = 2 * (residuals - (2 * nr_deviation - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation
        exponents.clip(-500, 500, out=exponents)
        updated_weights = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(exponents, dtype=np.float64))

        # Step 5f: Check for convergence by measuring how much the weights have changed
        if (norm(current_weights - updated_weights) / norm(current_weights)) < convergence_tolerance:
            break # Stop iterating if the change in weights is below the specified tolerance
        current_weights[:] = updated_weights

    # Step 6: Remove the padding and return the baseline corresponding to the original spectrum
    return baseline[edge_padding:-edge_padding]

This is roughly 26% faster.
Caching the creation of the penalty matrix
Next, I looked at the creation of the smoothness_penalies matrix. The key thing to notice about this matrix is that it depends on three things: the size of the spectrum, the smoothing factor, and the differentiation_order. These are the same for every call to arpls(). Since arpls() is called many times, this is a good candidate for memoization.
To do this, first move the creation of  smoothness_penalies into its own function. Next, apply the functools.lru_cache() decorator. This reduces the time spent setting up smoothness_penalies from 16% of execution time to 0.2%.
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy.sparse import csc_array, csr_array, dia_array, diags_array, eye_array
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache
def initialize_smoothness_penalies(size, differentiation_order, smoothing_factor):
    # Step 3: Initialize a difference array for enforcing smoothness
    differences: csr_array = eye_array(size, dtype=np.float64, format="csr")
    for _ in range(differentiation_order):
        # Update the difference array to account for higher-order differentials if required
        differences = differences[1:] - differences[:-1]

    # Step 4: Compute the smoothness penalties using the difference matrix and smoothing factor
    smoothness_penalies: csc_array = smoothing_factor * (differences.T @ differences)
    smoothness_penalies = smoothness_penalies.tocoo()
    smoothness_penalies.sum_duplicates()
    # smoothness_penalies must have canonical format, or changing to csr could change
    # data order
    assert smoothness_penalies.has_canonical_format
    initial_diag_index = np.where(smoothness_penalies.row == smoothness_penalies.col)[0]
    
    initial_diag = smoothness_penalies.data[initial_diag_index]
    smoothness_penalies = smoothness_penalies.tocsr()
    assert (smoothness_penalies.data[initial_diag_index] == smoothness_penalies.diagonal()).all()
    return smoothness_penalies, initial_diag, initial_diag_index


# Sparse array implementation
def arpls(
    spectrum: NDArray[np.floating],
    smoothing_factor: float = 1E6,
    convergence_tolerance: float = 0.05,
    differentiation_order: int = 2,
    max_iterations: int = 100,
    edge_padding: int = 100,
) -> NDArray[np.floating]:
    """
    Fits a baseline signal to the given spectrum using Asymmetrically Reweighted Penalized Least Squares smoothing.

    ### Parameters
    - spectrum: `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The 1D spectrum input array.
    - smoothing_factor: `float`, optional -- Smoothing strength parameter.\
        The larger the parameter, the smoother the resulting baseline.\
        High values suppress small fluctuations, which may lead to a smoother but less sensitive baseline.
    - convergence_tolerance: `float`, optional -- Convergence criterion based on the change in weights between iterations.\
        Must be a value between 0 and 1. Smaller values allow less negative deviations, promoting a more accurate baseline fitting.
    - differentiation_order: `int`, optional -- The order of the difference operator used in penalization.\
        An order of 1 enforces a linear baseline (smoothing the first derivative), while an order of 2 enforces a quadratic baseline (smoothing the second derivative).\
        Higher orders allow for more complex baseline shapes.
    - max_iterations: `int`, optional -- Maximum number of iterations to perform.\
        The algorithm iteratively refines the baseline until the convergence criterion is met or the maximum number of iterations is reached.
    - edge_padding: `int`, optional -- Number of points to pad on both ends of the spectrum to improve baseline fitting at the edges.\
        Padding is done using edge values to minimize boundary effects.

    ### Returns
    - `NDArray[np.floating]` -- The fitted baseline signal array of the same length as the input spectrum (after removing padding).

    ### Raises
    - `ValueError` -- If the ratio is not between 0 and 1.

    ### Reference
    - https://irfpy.irf.se/projects/ica/api/api_irfpy.ica.baseline.html#irfpy.ica.baseline.arpls

    ### Notes
    The ARPLS algorithm is particularly useful for baseline correction in spectra where the baseline is not well-defined and varies in a complex way.
    The algorithm iteratively adjusts the baseline by penalizing large deviations while allowing for asymmetric weighting, making it robust for various types of spectral data.
    """

    # Step 1: Pad the spectrum to reduce boundary effects during baseline fitting.
    padded_spectrum = np.pad(spectrum, pad_width=edge_padding, mode="edge")
    # Step 2: Initialize the weights array.
    current_weights = np.ones_like(padded_spectrum)
    smoothness_penalies, initial_diag, initial_diag_index = initialize_smoothness_penalies(padded_spectrum.shape[0], differentiation_order, smoothing_factor)

    A = smoothness_penalies.copy()

    # Step 5: Iteratively refine the estimated baseline
    baseline = np.zeros_like(padded_spectrum)
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # Step 5a: Generate a diagonal weights array from the current weights
        A.data[initial_diag_index] = initial_diag + current_weights
        # Step 5b: Solve for the baseline using the current weights and smoothness penalties
        b = current_weights * padded_spectrum
        baseline[:] = spsolve(A, b, permc_spec="NATURAL")

        # Step 5c: Calculate residuals (difference between the actual spectrum and the baseline)
        residuals = padded_spectrum - baseline
        # Step 5d: Calculate statistics of the negative residuals. Negative residuals indicate regions where the baseline may be overestimated
        negative_residuals = residuals[residuals < 0]
        nr_mean: np.floating = negative_residuals.mean(dtype=np.float64)
        nr_deviation: np.floating = negative_residuals.std(dtype=np.float64)

        # Step 5e: Update the weights to penalize large deviations while allowing for asymmetry. This step adjusts the baseline fitting to be more sensitive to regions below the baseline
        # Potential overflow in the original algorithm: "np.exp(2.0 * (residuals - ((2 * nr_deviation) - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation)"
        exponents = 2 * (residuals - (2 * nr_deviation - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation
        exponents.clip(-500, 500, out=exponents)
        updated_weights = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(exponents, dtype=np.float64))

        # Step 5f: Check for convergence by measuring how much the weights have changed
        if (norm(current_weights - updated_weights) / norm(current_weights)) < convergence_tolerance:
            break # Stop iterating if the change in weights is below the specified tolerance
        current_weights[:] = updated_weights

    # Step 6: Remove the padding and return the baseline corresponding to the original spectrum
    return baseline[edge_padding:-edge_padding]

This includes the previous optimization, and is roughly 36% faster than the original implementation.
Comparison to original results
The results are within a factor of 10-7 of the original, which is driven by changing the input of A to spsolve from CSC to CSR.
You could re-write initialize_smoothness_penalies to provide the results in CSC, but this does make spsolve slower.
Further work
Here are a set of ideas that I investigated and couldn't get to work. You may have more luck.

Iterative solvers: spsolve is a direct solver, but scipy has a number of iterative solvers. In theory, if you could identify a good initial guess for x0, like the baseline from the last iteration, then you could get the answer in very few iterations. In practice I could not get this to be faster than the direct solver. The best iterative solver that I found was cg, which was still slower.
umfpack: There is a note in the SciPy documentation that implies that umfpack based spsolve is faster than SciPy's solution. However, this depends on the scikit-umfpack package, which I couldn't get to install.


Thank to your guidance, I managed to boost its performance significantly. I posted an answer with the updated code for reference.

I tried a few of the iterative solvers, but guessing from the results, I think it would require a major rewrite of the algorithm... As for your second point on further work, having glanced at a few papers referenced for umfpack, I don't think it's worth the effort to compile.

A simple naive way to speed up this computation is just to run it on multiple cores thanks to multiple processes. Here is an example:
def parallel_arpls(spectra):
    results = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(joblib.delayed(arpls)(row) for row in spectra)
    return np.array(results)

Here are performance results on a Ryzen 7 5700U CPU with 8 cores:
%timeit -n 1 np.apply_along_axis(arpls, axis=1, arr=spectra)
1.81 s ± 57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit -n 1 parallel_arpls(spectra)
484 ms ± 66.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

This is 3.7 times faster. This does not scale very well, but this has the benefit of being very simple.
To get significantly better performance, I think one should write a faster implementation of spsolve. However, this is certainly a really huge work (even for a skilled developer). An alternative solution might be to implement an alternative algorithm using less iteration or a more direct approach (this require a good understanding of the underlying math).

Thanks to Nick ODell's suggestions, I managed to improve performance by more than 300% compared to the original code. Here's the updated algorithm for reference:
from functools import lru_cache

import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy.sparse import coo_array, csc_array, csr_array, eye_array
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve


# Only need to cache up to two parameter sets
@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def generate_penalties(
    shape: int,
    differentiation_order: int,
    smoothing_factor: float,
) -> tuple[NDArray[np.floating], csr_array, NDArray[np.floating], NDArray[np.intp]]:
    """
    Generates the initial weights and smoothness penalty matrix used in the ARPLS algorithm.

    This function precomputes the structures needed for penalizing deviations during baseline correction, which are reused across iterations.
    To optimize performance, it caches the results using `lru_cache`, allowing for reuse if the function is called again with the same parameters.

    ### Parameters
    - shape: `int` -- The length of the spectrum for which penalties are generated.
    - differentiation_order: `int` -- The order of the difference operator used in penalization. See the ARPLS docstring for more details.
    - smoothing_factor: `float` -- Controls the smoothness of the resulting baseline. See the ARPLS docstring for more details.

    ### Returns
    - weights: `NDArray[floating]` -- Initial weights array, all set to 1, indicating uniform weighting before any iterations.
    - smoothness_penalties: `csr_array` -- A sparse matrix representing the smoothness penalties to be applied during baseline fitting.
    - diagonal: `NDArray[floating]` -- The initial diagonal values of the penalty matrix, stored for efficient updates during iterations.
    - diagonal_indices: `NDArray[intp]` -- Indices where diagonal elements are located in the sparse matrix data array.

    ### Notes
    The caching mechanism assumes that the function is called with similar parameters multiple times, which helps in optimizing performance in repeated baseline fitting tasks.
    """

    # Initialize the weights array to all ones, indicating no preference for any part of the spectrum initially
    weights = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.float32)

    # Create a sparse identity matrix and apply the difference operator iteratively to build the smoothness penalty matrix
    differences = csr_array(eye_array(shape, dtype=np.float64, format="csr"))
    for _ in range(differentiation_order):
        # Subtracts shifted matrices to build higher-order differences
        differences = csr_array(differences[1:] - differences[:-1])

    # Apply the smoothing factor to the penalty matrix, converting it to a compressed sparse column format for efficient computation
    smoothness_penalties = csc_array(smoothing_factor * (differences.T @ differences))
    smoothness_penalties = coo_array(smoothness_penalties.tocoo())
    # Ensure there are no duplicate entries in the sparse matrix
    smoothness_penalties.sum_duplicates()

    # Identify and store the diagonal elements for quick updates during baseline fitting iterations
    diagonal_indices: NDArray[np.intp] = np.where(smoothness_penalties.row == smoothness_penalties.col)[0]
    diagonal = smoothness_penalties.data[diagonal_indices]
    # Convert to CSR format for solving the linear system
    smoothness_penalties = csr_array(smoothness_penalties.tocsr())

    return weights, smoothness_penalties, diagonal, diagonal_indices


def arpls(
    spectrum: NDArray[np.floating],
    edge_padding: int = 100,
    differentiation_order: int = 2,
    smoothing_factor: float = 1E6,
    convergence_tolerance: float = 0.05,
    max_iterations: int = 100,
) -> NDArray[np.floating]:
    """
    Fits a baseline signal to the given spectrum using the Asymmetrically Reweighted Penalized Least Squares algorithm.

    This method iteratively fits a smooth baseline to a given spectrum by minimizing the effect of noise while preserving the original signal's characteristics.
    The ARPLS algorithm adjusts the baseline by asymmetrically penalizing negative deviations, making it particularly robust for spectral data with varying baseline shapes.

    ### Parameters
    - spectrum: `NDArray[floating]` -- The 1D spectrum input array.
    - edge_padding: `int` -- Number of points to pad on both ends of the spectrum to improve baseline fitting at the edges.\
        Padding is done using edge values to minimize boundary effects.
    - differentiation_order: `int` -- The order of the difference operator used in penalization.\
        An order of 1 enforces a linear baseline (smoothing the first derivative), while an order of 2 enforces a quadratic baseline (smoothing the second derivative).\
        Higher orders allow for more complex baseline shapes.
    - smoothing_factor: `float` -- Controls the smoothness of the resulting baseline.\
        Larger values suppress small fluctuations, which may lead to a smoother, but less sensitive baseline.
    - convergence_tolerance: `float` -- Convergence criterion based on the change in weights between iterations.\
        Must be a value between 0 and 1. Smaller values allow less negative deviations, promoting a more accurate baseline fitting.
    - max_iterations: `int` -- Maximum number of iterations to perform.\
        The algorithm iteratively refines the baseline until the convergence criterion is met or the maximum number of iterations is reached.

    ### Returns
    - `NDArray[floating]` -- The fitted baseline signal array of the same length as the input spectrum (after removing padding).

    ### Reference
    Asymmetrically Reweighted Penalized Least Squares for Baseline Correction: https://irfpy.irf.se/projects/ica/api/api_irfpy.ica.baseline.html#irfpy.ica.baseline.arpls

    ### Notes
    The ARPLS algorithm is particularly useful for baseline correction in spectra where the baseline is not well-defined and varies in a complex way.
    The algorithm iteratively adjusts the baseline by penalizing large deviations while allowing for asymmetric weighting, making it robust for various types of spectral data.
    """

    # Step 1: Pad the spectrum to mitigate boundary effects, which helps in obtaining a more accurate baseline
    padded_spectrum = np.pad(spectrum, pad_width=edge_padding, mode="edge")
    # Step 2: Generate initial weights, penalty matrix, and indices for diagonal elements
    weights, penalties, diagonal, diagonal_index = generate_penalties(padded_spectrum.shape[0], differentiation_order, smoothing_factor)

    # Step 4: Begin iterative refinement of the baseline using updated weights and penalties
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # Step 5a: Update the diagonal elements of the penalty matrix with the current weights.
        penalties.data[diagonal_index] = diagonal + weights
        # Step 5b: Solve the linear system to obtain the new baseline.
        baseline: NDArray[np.floating] = spsolve(penalties, weights * padded_spectrum, permc_spec="NATURAL", use_umfpack=False)

        # Step 5c: Calculate residuals (difference between the actual spectrum and the baseline)
        residuals = padded_spectrum - baseline
        # Step 5d: Extract the negative residuals, which indicate regions where the baseline may be overestimated
        negative_residuals = residuals[residuals < 0]
        if not negative_residuals.size:
            break # Stop iterating if residuals are all positive

        # Step 5e: Calculate statistics of the negative residuals.
        nr_mean: np.floating = negative_residuals.mean(dtype=np.float64)
        nr_deviation: np.floating = negative_residuals.std(dtype=np.float64)

        # Step 5f: Update the weights to penalize large deviations while allowing for asymmetry. This step adjusts the baseline fitting to be more sensitive to regions below the baseline
        # Potential overflow in the original algorithm: "np.exp(2.0 * (residuals - ((2 * nr_deviation) - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation)"
        exponents = 2 * (residuals - (2 * nr_deviation - nr_mean)) / nr_deviation
        exponents.clip(-500, 500, out=exponents)
        updated_weights = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(exponents, dtype=np.float64))

        # Step 5g: Check for convergence by measuring how much the weights have changed
        if (norm(weights - updated_weights) / norm(weights)) < convergence_tolerance:
            break # Stop iterating if the change in weights is below the specified tolerance

        # Step 5h: Update the weights for the next iteration
        weights[:] = updated_weights

    # Step 6: Remove the padding and return the baseline corresponding to the original spectrum
    return baseline[edge_padding:-edge_padding]

As suggested by Jérôme Richard, multithreading is most likely to be the next step.
